# find data from mongo with python

Tags: python, pymongo

For example, I have a mongo table with the following attributes:

```
userid, age, name
```

Now I want to get the userid of all users who have the attribute "age".
How should I achieve this with python? I should use "exist" right?

Comment: Please take some time to read the docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/. The queries in PyMongo are typically exactly the same as the normal Mongo syntax.

Comment: @lilian417 is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job:

```
user_list=list(db.test.find({"age":{"$exists":True}},{"userid":1}))
#list of all the users
key_value = [i['userid'] for i in user_list]
```